# Only animate when tab is not slided out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this tab slider which moves a little when you hover the tab. I would like this to happen only when the slider is not slided out. When it's out it shouldn't move on hover.
[See working example here](http://jsbin.com/AGAZEhe/5).

The slider gets the class "open" when it's sliding out, so I have tried adding this code:

```
if (!$("#contactContainer").hasClass("open")) {
    $("#contactContainer").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        "right": "+=30px"
    }, 300); }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        "right": "-=30px"
    }, 300); });
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to make any difference. The open slider still moves when hovering it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is only adding the hover functionality when the container isn't open -- since this happens on load (when the container isn't open) the hover functionality is always there.

There are a few ways round this, the simplest is to check inside the hover function if the container is open, try this:

```
$("#contactContainer").hover(
    function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "+=45px"}, 300);
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "-=45px"}, 300);
        }
    }
);
```

Alternatively implement a closed class and use CSS animations on that class directly to do the move. Or add/remove the hover functionality as part of the open/close functionality. The above solution is easiest but may have some issues depending on the exact functionality you want.

Comment: Good fix, but it has an issue: the tab animates back to its original point, and because the hover is triggered after the click it keeps going past the edge of the screen. See below for a workaround.

Comment: @MassivePenguin (great username, btw) yeah -- I only checked it quickly and had a sneaking suspicion I was leaving myself open to a bug like that -- and that's a nice workaround, didn't think of checking `:animated`. I also think the open position will be +45 pts offset from what's intended as the mousein will happen but not the mouseout.

Answer (score 2):

Using SpaceDog's example, the slider closes but continues to animate offscreen. This is because the 'open' class is removed immediately, and as your mouse is over the container the hover behaviour is triggered (moving the tab off the left of the screen by 45 pixels, and preventing the user from clicking it again).

If you check for the ':animated' property as well, you can prevent the hover behaviour from triggering, and therefore keep the tab onscreen:

```
$("#contactContainer").hover(
    function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open") && !$(this).is(":animated")) {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "+=45px"}, 300);
    }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open") && !$(this).is(":animated")) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "-=45px"}, 300);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move that if statement into your hover function and animate only if it does not have the class open.

Your if check is currently only checking the container when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the use the [on-method of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This will bind to the mouseenter and mouseleave elements of the document, and then check if they bubbled up from an element which matches the selector.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#contactContainer:not(.open)", function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "+=45px"}, 300);
}).on("mouseleave", "#contactContainer:not(.open)", function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"right": "-=45px"}, 300);
});
```